Black Spots in Cycle Render Render
So I am doing a character in Blender, I realized that on the lips are black spots (only on thr lips). I tried to fix my mesh but it didnt help.
close up of the dark spot problem


Seems like that has to do with the textures, not the mesh. Look at the BaseColor map and see if those spots appear there.
